# Trouble using gcloud init

Tags: macos, git, gcloud

Saw a sweet video on gcloud and wanted to give it a shot but was stymied at the start.  I did the setup, downloaded the tools, ran gcloud auth login, all good.  Tried to init a project and got an error I'm not sure how to fix.

```
$ gcloud init my-awesome-project-555
Initialized gcloud directory in [/Users/freddy/my-awesome-project-555/.gcloud].
Cloning [https://source.developers.google.com/p/my-awesome-project-555/r/default] into [default].
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/freddy/my-awesome-project-555/default/.git/
fatal: remote error: 403 Forbidden
ERROR: Unable to initialize project [my-awesome-project-555], cleaning up [/Users/freddy/my-awesome-project-555].
ERROR: (gcloud.init) Could not fetch repository.
$
```

For good measure:

```
$ which git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
$ git --version
git version 1.7.12.1
$
```

I'm on a macbook air with OSX 10.9.2

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: You did declare that project `my-awesome-project-555` in your dev console (https://console.developers.google.com/project) first, right?

Answer (score 3):

The integration between gcloud auth and git only works for git clients version 1.8 and up.  Please try updating your git client and try again.  We will add a more clear error message for this in a future release.  Thanks!

Comment: I do have git 1.8.5.2, as well as owning the current project, still getting same error as OP.

Answer (score 0):

The 403 indicates that you do not own my-awesome-project-555. You can use the cloud console (https://console.developers.google.com/project) to create a new project, and use that project ID with 'gcloud init'.

Comment: This answer is not correct in my case. I *do* own and have access to said project. The thing is I have two different accounts with respectively completely different projects and trying to use gcloud with both on them on one computer(one os x account) just won't work. I can't access one or the other if I have several accounts authed (gcloud auth list). It doesn't matter if the needed account is the one set as default/current. I normally have to revoke all accounts from gcloud, then readd the one I need for things to work.

Comment: You can do 'gcloud auth login ACCOUNT' to switch between accounts that you already have credentials for. There is no need to revoke and relogin in - the tokens you get by doing that are no different than the ones you already had. To be sure you have the right account active, see if it's indicated in 'gcloud auth list'. If the indicated account has access to the project that is getting 403'd, then there is something you're not telling us.

Comment: Perhaps the repository does not exist? For some older projects, you need to click the "Create repository" button in the Cloud Console before it will exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to see 403 errors, you may need to obtain credentials to an existing repo.  Obtain credentials by clicking the "Get credentials" button in the source repository settings.  Save this in a .netrc file and try to commit again.

Comment: What happens if there are two entries in netrc for two projects. the command files with the same 403. if I remove one entry it works again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed the order of authenticated e-mails in ~/.netrc file just moving the desired account to the first line. I think it is a bug, since appears that only the first credential in the .netrc file is used when cloning or pushing.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to put your project Id, you have to run the gcloud init  first, after that you will be asked which service account or user account to init the configuration and then finish the configuration.
the 'gcloud init' no longer takes a PROJECT argument.