# gcloud init fails for invalid username/password

Tags: macos, git, gcloud

I am trying to gain access to the embedded git repository for an existing Google Developers Console (GDC) project. The GDC shows the git repository under -SOURCE CODE-Releases. I followed the official gcloud installation instructions to the point:

```
gcloud auth login /* pulls up browser and does authentication just fine */
gcloud config set project <project>
gcloud init <project>
```

The latter always results in the following (replacing actual project name with 'fishbone'):

```
$gcloud init fishbone
Initialized gcloud directory in [/Users/dummy/Workspace/fishbone/.gcloud].
Cloning [https://source.developers.google.com/p/fishbone/r/default] into [default].
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/dummy/Workspace/fishbone/default/.git/
fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your OAuth token password; Note that generated google.com passwords are not compatible with private repositories
ERROR: Unable to initialize project [fishbone], cleaning up [/Users/dummy/Workspace/fishbone].
ERROR: (gcloud.init) Could not fetch repository.
```

Only on the very first installation of the SDK (re-tried more than once now), I remember gcloud init asking for a username. Never again after this. Mac OS X 10.9.3 and:

```
$git --version
$git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
```

I am aware of [this related gcloud init issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23355252/trouble-using-gcloud-init), but it's not this. Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project/your-project-id > Source Code > Browse > Find this line : "Alternatively, instead of using the Google Cloud SDK to manage your authentication, you can manually generate your Git credentials by following this link." > Click "following this link" and you can see your git password. As you can see in your error, google password are not compatible with private repositories. Now you can :

- Use your gmail and git password above to clone reposite.
- Or create .netrc file at your home folder and add : "machine source.developers.google.com login your-email@gmail.com password 1/abxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" to this file. It will not request your password again.

Answer (score 0):

Just goto your Google Developer Console and click /
find the content like below

"Alternatively, instead of using the Google Cloud SDK to manage your authentication, you can manually generate your Git credentials by following this link."

and click "following this link" then follow the instructions on that page.

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

They moved the options to manually created Git credentials. The options are now under GCP -> (tools) Development -> Source Code 
and under the options when cloning new or existing repos they give you the option to use gcloud or create your own credentials.

also below in screenshots 
[image: Get Starter]

[image: Google Cloud SDK (Recommended)]

[image: Manually Generate, Follow Dropdown]